# Div element in Phaser3

Tags: phaser-framework

My code:

```js
let div1 = document.createElement('div');
div1.style = 'background-color: lime; width: 220px; height: 100px; font: 48px Arial; font-weight: bold';
div1.innerText = 'Phaser 3';
this.add.dom(300, 0, div1);
```

I'm trying to add a **div with text-element**. Everything is ok, but text isn't visible. What's the matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `y` value is too low. You are successfully adding the `div` element to your `DOM` but it's adding it at an *y coordinate* of 0 so you can't see the full element.

Try changing to this:

```
this.add.dom(300, 200, div1);
```